# hosting my web portal on CentOS linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I need to buy a VPS / dedicated server that provides a CentOS Linux with 4 x 500 GB harddrives in mirrored Raid. So that'd be 1TB of hard-drive space.

The way I keep my pictures on my website is in a single folder, where all the picture of the same type go, with the id of the `mysql_row` in front, followed by a short description.

Something like *1_thumb.jpg* or *123_index.jpg*, they all go in the same folder.

The question is : Since I will have multiple hard-drives on my hosting `/dev/hda1`, `/dev/hda2` in Raid mirrored, Can they make a whole big 1TB partition from all of the hard-drives combined ?

If so, I can use the current structure of my website. If not, then I need to rethink the way I keep my pictures saved.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a dedicated server, which means you are in control of the kernel, you can. The tool you are looking for is `mdadm`. A good howto can be found [here](http://linuxconfig.org/Linux_Software_Raid_1_Setup). It's a Debian howto so it differs in the packages you need to install, but you should have similar packages for CentOS.

Comment: ah so I can make 1 huge 1TB partition out of the 4 Raid mirrored hdds ? :)) thanks :) well...I get a root-shell to it, but they will install it. I think I might suggest'em to do this as a start, so I won't need to modify it later.